# Photoshop CS6 Cropping Problem

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

I'm having a trouble cropping at all sizes when using `W x H x Resolution`.  For example, I choose `500px` as `W` and `H`, and then `300ppi` for `resolution`- and then I have to wait. And I mean **WAIT ALL DAY**. The progess bar just stops at a certain point.

Do I have something set wrong?

Comment: what was the images resolution originally ? - equally could you show us a screenshot

Comment: Thx for answering! The original image was 3072 x 2304 180ppi resolution. It also happens with other resolutions. off the top of my head: 710 x 410 x 72ppi

Comment: It say I need 10 reputation points to post an image...

Comment: Upvoting your question to give you the points ;)

Comment: if you post a link to the image someone can edit your post to show it

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/94368635@N03/8590841636/

Comment: What are your computer's stats?  how much ram? processor speed? Are you using a graphic card? What are your photoshop's Graphics processor settings or just performance settings? (Preferences > performance

Comment: Screeen shot is a bit pointless. I don't know what would be gained by seeing a screenshot. The issue may be due to your changing dimensions while also changing resolution and your system configuration. What happens if you first change the image ppi to 300 with `resample image` **unchecked** and then crop to the dimensions you want?

Answer (score 3):

your have typed units in "inches", make them to px(pixel).
[image]

Comment: Oooh. Ouch. Poor CPU.